# ¿Cómo implementar un Chart con datos de un servicio en Angular?

Tags: array, angular, typescript

Tengo este `Chart` que funciona con datos locales y quiero llenar `series:[[]]` con datos de un servicio.

```
barChart: Chart = {
    type: 'Bar',
    data: {
      labels: ['M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S', 'S'],
      series: [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]]
    }
```

El servicio es este.

```
leerInfoDays():void{
    this.salesService.leerinfoDays().subscribe(
      (res:SaleDays[]) =>{
          this.listasalesdays = res;
      })}

[{"v1":"40","v2":"45","v3":"70","v4":"35","v5":"60","v6":"65","v7":"75"}]
```

He intentado de esta forma pero no obtengo el resultado esperado.

```
SalesDays = this.listasalesdays;
series: [Object.values(this.SalesDays[0]).map(e => parseInt(e) ? parseInt(e) : e)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes resolverlo de esta manera:

```js
 constructor() {

   let  SalesDays = [{"v1":"40","v2":"45","v3":"70","v4":"35","v5":"60","v6":"65","v7":"75"}]

  let series = []
  for( let dato in SalesDays[0]){
    series.push( SalesDays[0][dato])
  }

  let bartChart= { series: [ series ]}
       console.log(bartChart)
  }
```

Te dejo un [ejemplo funcional](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wprbup) para que lo pruebes.